# function m(str) { stuff } Is returning error? help with logic please

Tags: php

A post by https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince on one of my old questions has the below code.

Except i cannot seem to work out how to implement this method of creating functions to streamline the process of re-using some common php commands.

But it wont work?

I have this:

```
function m(str) { return "'".mysql_real_escape_string(str)."'"; }

function h(str) { echo htmlspecialchars(str); }

function u(str) { echo rawurlencode(str); }
```

I get this error?

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in /home/dev/public_html/tpm/templates/tpm/index.php on line 79`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP [variable names](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) begin with a `$` dollar sign.

You should have written `$str` instead of `str`:

```
function h($str) { echo htmlspecialchars($str); }
```